# Copy consecutive rows and paste rows in every other row in another speadsheet - Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro running to insert a blank rows between every existing row in sheet1, I now need to paste data from another sheet to those blank rows, the copied data is in consecutive rows.

Can anyone help me in a coding to paste this data?

```
Sub InsertBlankRows()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'Step1:  Declare your variables.
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
    
'Step 2:  Define the target Range.
    Set MyRange = Range("A2:F21")
    
'Step 3:  Start reverse looping through the range.
    For iCounter = MyRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    
'Step 4: Insert two blank rows.
    MyRange.Rows(iCounter).EntireRow.Insert

'Step 5: Increment the counter down
    Next iCounter
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to copy rows(x) and paste to rows(y) where y=x*2 +(starting row-1 on worksheet you are copying from)